# What to use in keras >2.0 in place of merge with mode='mul'?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to modify some code that was made for Keras<2.0 and I stumbled upon this line of code:

```
output_attention_mul = merge([inputs, a_probs], name='attention_mul', mode='mul')
```

How can I translate this line of code in Keras>2.0?

I've tried using the `Multiply` layer this way

```
output_attention_mul = Multiply()([inputs, a_probs])
```

but I don't really know if that's the right thing to do since in the old code it's used the `merge` operation and not the `Merge` layer.

Can anybody confirm me if I did the right thing or if I used a wrong approach? Should I use `multiply` instead of `Multiply`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `keras.layers.Multiply()`

Which should then give you `output_attention_mul = keras.layers.Multiply()([inputs, a_probs])`

You should be able to find in the documentation here: https://keras.io/layers/merge/

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yup, I tried using it already and it seemed to work, although I'm not quite sure if that's the right thing to do, that's why I asked

Comment: I'm sorry I miss understood. In Keras 2 the module merge is replaced by their subclasses which in this case are capitalized so `.Add`, `.Merge` ect. If you want to call their functional interfaces you would use the lower case name. In this case, you would be looking to use capital letters. So what you did is correct. My apologies for the confusion.